# How to sort through a list of observable coordinates?

Tags: python, coordinates, astronomy, astropy

I am struggling to find the best way of removing unwanted targets from a list of coordinates. My coordinates (Ra, Dec) are formed using `astropy.coordinates.SkyCoord` but I have a large number of un-observable targets that are too low in declination, so what I want to do is sort through my list and remove all targets with a declination lower than -10 degrees for example (as my telescope is in the northern hemisphere).

This is the line of my code that produces the list, its called `radecs` for simplification and gets the Ra & Dec from celestial spherical coordinates.

```
radecs = astropy.coordinates.SkyCoord(ra=phi*u.rad, dec=(0.5*np.pi - theta)*u.rad)
```

And this is an example of how my list off coordinates is outputted in Python.

```
<SkyCoord (ICRS): (ra, dec) in deg
    [(45.0, 60.0), (135.0, 45.0), (225.0, 25.0), ...,
    (135.0, 55.0), (225.0, 70.0), (315.0, -20.0)]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just illustrate how you can use numpy indexing with boolean masks on some arbitary coordinates:

```
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
import astropy.units as u
import numpy as np
phi = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,20)
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 20)
radecs = SkyCoord(ra=phi*u.rad, dec=(0.5*np.pi - theta)*u.rad)
radecs
```

giving me `radecs`:

```
<SkyCoord (ICRS): (ra, dec) in deg
    [(0.0, 90.0), (18.94736842, 80.52631579), (37.89473684, 71.05263158),
     (56.84210526, 61.57894737), (75.78947368, 52.10526316),
     (94.73684211, 42.63157895), (113.68421053, 33.15789474),
     (132.63157895, 23.68421053), (151.57894737, 14.21052632),
     (170.52631579, 4.73684211), (189.47368421, -4.73684211),
     (208.42105263, -14.21052632), (227.36842105, -23.68421053),
     (246.31578947, -33.15789474), (265.26315789, -42.63157895),
     (284.21052632, -52.10526316), (303.15789474, -61.57894737),
     (322.10526316, -71.05263158), (341.05263158, -80.52631579),
     (0.0, -90.0)]>
```

to get the `dec` (declination) of your `radecs` you can acces the property:

```
radecs.dec

[90, 80.526316, 71.052632, 61.578947, 52.105263, 42.631579, 33.157895, 23.684211, 14.210526, 4.7368421, −4.7368421, −14.210526, −23.684211, −33.157895, −42.631579, −52.105263, −61.578947, −71.052632, −80.526316, −90]
```

so we can access all targets with a declination above `-10` degree by creating a mask:

```
radecs.dec > - 10 * u.degree
```

and then index all targets which satisfy this mask:

```
radecs2 = radecs[radecs.dec > - 10 * u.degree]
```

Giving me the following `radecs2`:

```
<SkyCoord (ICRS): (ra, dec) in deg
    [(0.0, 90.0), (18.94736842, 80.52631579), (37.89473684, 71.05263158),
     (56.84210526, 61.57894737), (75.78947368, 52.10526316),
     (94.73684211, 42.63157895), (113.68421053, 33.15789474),
     (132.63157895, 23.68421053), (151.57894737, 14.21052632),
     (170.52631579, 4.73684211), (189.47368421, -4.73684211)]>
```

essentially all you do is the last step (`radecs2 = radecs[radecs.dec > - 10 * u.degree]`), all the other steps are just explanatory.

Comment: Great, thanks @MSeifert, I knew it would be straightforward but I wasnt sure if the Ra coordinates would carry through with the "masked" Declination coordinates.

Comment: Does this also work for an astropy.Table? I have a third value added to the Ra & Dec in this table which is for the apparent magnitudes of the stars. I realised that when i try the new "radecs2" list of coordinates, this list is now shorter in length than the corresponding list of magnitudes I have in my table, so the mask doesnt transpose over to my third column.

Comment: @Dean: That's a different question. Please open another question showing how you created that Table and what you want to do. :)

Comment: I have done this now, you can find it here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011398/how-to-sort-through-a-list-of-observable-coordinates-part-2), thanks for the advice. :)